# net maui popup extends outside of control in MVVM application?

Tags: mvvm, popup, maui

I'm trying to use the toolkit:Popup from CommunityToolkit but when rendering controls from the xaml they extend "outside" of the controls visible area (see screenshot)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
               x:Class="MyApp.Controls.AlertPopup">
    <Grid
        BackgroundColor="#333333"
        WidthRequest="150"
        Margin="20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Text="My title" />
        <Label 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="lorem ipsum dolor amet lorem ipsum dolor amet lorem ipsum dolor amet " />
        <Button
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Text="Continue" />
    </Grid>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

Displaying the popup in the MVVM viewmodel

```
[ICommand]
async Task DisplayPopup()
{
    Shell.Current.CurrentPage.ShowPopup(new MyApp.Controls.AlertPopup());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Size` of the element property in the Maui popup.

Gets or sets the Size of the Popup Display. The Popup will always try to constrain the actual size of the Popup to the size of the View unless a Size is specified. If the Popup uses the HorizontalOptions or VerticalOptions properties that are not the defaults then this Size property is required.

---

Update

For the Grid, I find that the `widthrequest` controls the popup window width but the  `<ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />`  controls the text and elements width. So you need to set the ColumnWidth to match the popup window width.

Comment: I set the width of the frame with WidthRequest="150". If I omit it, it takes up the whole with of the simulator. For a X-plattform technology it seems weird to set a width but I could live with that. The main problem is that the control inside the frame is not constrained by its parent. The second label does not line break and thus I guess that button follows the label. I can get it to work if I set width requests on all components but that's no good. I want to set the width on the fram and for children be working with margin and padding.

Comment: I found that the popup width is actually controlled by the `<ColumnDefinition Width="200" />` , So you can only set the ColumnDefinition width for the Grid and remove  `WidthRequest="150" `  and `Margin="20"`. If you want to set the Margin you can set it in the elements like label and button.